# ElasticSearch Query

Tags: json, elasticsearch

I need to make a query in elasticsearch, such that, in the following text:
"I want to go on holiday to New York with my family" find: "New York" in the field of a nested.
I in my data I have a field that contains the word "New York" which is the type Nested and not_analyzed.
Anyone know how to do this?

The query and I got it, and nobody help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a [phrase query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/match-query/). From the docs:

```
{
   "match_phrase" : {
       "message" : "this is a test"
   }
}
```

I do think that having "not_analyzed" is going to be a problem for you, as you actually want an analyzed field. You can specify the type of analyzer to use, which may work. But I would recommend using an analyzed field, if possible.

If you are willing to pay the space cost, I would recommend using a multi field with analyzed and not_analyzed parts. here is an example:

```
 "sender": {
            "type" : "multi_field",
            "fields" : {
                "sender" : {"type" : "string", "index" : "analyzed"},
                "sender_not_analyzed" : {"type" : "string", "index" : "not_analyzed"}
            }
        }
```

Comment: I have to use it well, because I need to be not_analyzed, because that field is another query filter.
Changing the type, as do the query?

Comment: More on this exact same use case here: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/aggregations-and-analysis.html

Answer (score 0):

`not_analyzed` means what it says, it isn't analyzed.  It will be indexed as the literal string passed in, in a single token.  If you make it analyzed, it will be tokenized and filtered in such a way as to make it useful for full-text searching.  So do that.

Please see the documentation of [ElasticSearch Analysis](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/index-modules/analysis/).

Comment: You change `not_analyzed` to `analyzed`.

Comment: Probably a phrasequery would be ideal, but I recommend you read up on some [basic match queries](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/match-query/) as well.

Comment: Surprisingly rude, toward a couple people trying to help you, not sure what prompted that.  Seriously though, `not_analyzed` is not correct, and should be changed, for this type of search.  I imagine you have switched to a `WildcardQuery`, or something along those lines if you kept with a `not_analyzed` field, which means it will perform a linear search through the entire index, and performance on large data sets will drop through the floor.

Comment: I and @Paul_Sanwald both answered the question as well as possible given the information provided.  If you ended up using a different approach, you should provide an answer indicating as much, instead.

Comment: Not what you asked, if you do not understand, and I have no way to explain to you. Stop giving negative points when it's you who does not answer what is asked.